# It doesn't work on the first click, but does on the second one. How to fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have function like this, it doesn't work on the first click, but does on the second one. How to fix that?

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
let dis = document.getElementsByClassName('display');

document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(coll[0].style.display == 'none') 
  {
    coll[0].style.display = 'block';
    dis[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
  else 
  {
    coll[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.collection {
    width: 80vh;
    height: 85vh;
    background-color: blue;

    display: none;
    grid-column: 4 / 10;
    grid-row: 2 / 9;
    justify-self: center;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection"></div>
```

(and yes - I was looking for case like that before, but most of it is jQuery, and I don't get it, please help)

Comment: You haven't added the HTML for the `menu-btn1` or `display` elements.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('display')` is missing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `coll[0].style.display = 'block';` search for an inline-style and you're adding the `display: none;` on a css class, if you're checking the styles, you need to add the inline style like this:

```
<div class="collection" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Here you can see the snippet with the correct styles

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
let dis = document.getElementsByClassName('display');

document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(coll[0].style.display == 'none') 
  {
    coll[0].style.display = 'block';
    //dis[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
  else 
  {
    coll[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.collection {
    width: 80vh;
    height: 85vh;
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 4 / 10;
    grid-row: 2 / 9;
    justify-self: center;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection" style="display:none;">
</div>

<button id="menu-btn1">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest cleaning up your code and using a class toggle to hide and show it

your CSS:

```
.collection {
    width: 80vh;
    height: 85vh;
    background-color: blue;

    grid-column: 4 / 10;
    grid-row: 2 / 9;
    justify-self: center;
    z-index: 3;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="collection hidden"></div>
<div class"display"></div> <!--I was assuming your .display element was visible at first and you wanted to hide it afterwards-->
```

Your JS:

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
let dis = document.getElementsByClassName('display');

document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  coll[0].classList.toggle("hidden");
  dis[0].classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

This way your code is cleaner, and since you create a separate class for the `display: none;` you're avoiding icky issues about the hierarchy of selector styles in CSS when you apply that "display: none;" to all elements of that class but only try to change the display for one of the elements in that class

Comment: This is excellent! Saved me some hair pulling